# Why are conversions from "class A : IX" to generic "T where T : IX" not allowed?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, type-constraints

Why does the following cause a compilation error?

```
interface IX {}
interface IY {}
class XY : IX, IY {}

void Foo<T>() where T : IX, IY
{
    T xy = new XY();
    …   // ^^^^^^^^
}       // error: "Implicit conversion of type 'XY' to 'T' is not possible."
```

---

**Note:** The same error would occur if `class XY : IX` and `where T : IX`. However, I have chosen a more complex example because a simpler one might have provoked circumventive answers such as, *"Just change the type of `xy` from `T` to `IX`"*, which would not answer *why* this conversion fails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given `class ABC : IX, IY { }` and `Foo<ABC>`, would you expect to be able to use `new XY()` then? Because you shouldn't have that expectation. The compiler will not, either.

T is not always going to be XY. T is going to be ABC, DEF, or *anything else* that could implement your two interfaces and therefore meet the constraints you have. XY is not convertible to ABC, DEF, or *any of the infinite possibilities for T*, and therefore you have your error message: the implicit conversion of XY to T is not possible.

What would be legal there is simply `new T()`, and this is true *only* if the method is constrained to support it.

```
void Foo<T>() where T : IX, IY, new()
{
    T obj = new T();
}
```

Comment: I keep repeating the same error in reasoning over and over again when it comes to generic type constraints. Thanks for your very clear explanation.

Comment: @stakx: I suspect that you are reasoning in the wrong direction. The constraint means *any T is convertible to the given interface type*, not *anything that implements this interface is convertible to T*.

Comment: @Eric, precisely! If you wouldn't mind, could you confirm another suspicion that's just occurred to me? Could the distinction also be made as follows... **Correct reasoning:** `T` gets chosen by the caller of `Foo`, and not by `Foo` itself. This makes `T` a universal type (at least for `Foo`). **Wrong reasoning** (i.e. me, 3 hours ago): `T` gets chosen by `Foo` and not by its caller. This makes it an existential type (at least for the caller of `Foo`).

Answer (score 15):

Because if that were legal then you could do this:

```
interface IPet {} 
interface IMammal {} 
class Dog : IPet, IMammal {}  
class Cat : IPet, IMammal {}
T Foo<T>() where T : IPet, IMammal
{     
  return new Dog();
}
...
Cat cat = Foo<Cat>();  // Assigns a Dog to a variable of type Cat.
```